# 3d object navigator and move

Tags: swift, object, 3d

I'm searching for a method to implement an app with swift 3. I would like to insert a window where I can view a 3D object and move it (like zoom, rotation etc).
Is it possible? How can I do it?
Thank you so much.
Lorenzo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Apple technology that you need to look into is called SceneKit.  SceneKit is a toolbox for creating and viewing 3D objects and... well... scenes.  It is high level and easy to work with, but makes effective use of much lower level, performant technologies.  The developer documentation can be found here:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit